# Reversing a list of string elements in Python 3.x

Tags: python, list, return, reverse

### When I run this code:

```
def ex():
    a = "ante kai pidiksou".split()
    b = a.reverse()
    print(b)
ex()
```

---

I get `None` as a result. When I put, instead of `print(b), print(a)`, I get `['pidiksou', 'kai', 'ante']` which is what I want.

My query is: Why it does print variable `a` reversed even if I haven't assigned its reversed value to it (variable `a`)? And why it doesn't print variable `b`?

Answer (score 3):

`reverse` is an in-place operation, which means it modifies `a`. To return a *new* list of strings without changing the original one, use `list(reversed(a))`. For many purposes, you can also use the iterator `reversed(a)` directly.

Comment: list(reversed(a)) I'd say, it's an iterator

Comment: I edited my answer.